# Valid meanings for the word smart

Tags: meaning

Is it valid to call a person "smart" as to mean well educated?

Comment: '... someone how is a varying Intellectual person?' please clarify or re word your question

Comment: Valid yet not very smart.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary for the definition of the word? What did it say? Please include what you've found so far in the dictionary and why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think smart refers to the good function of a persons brain and is not a suitable choice for education.

Comment: A person who has not had the opportunity to gain an education may still be naturally intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you had intended to type the word, "who" rather than "how".  Yes, the word, "smart" in contemporary American English means someone who is well educated through some type of education, whether it be by formal or informal education; such as reading for and on behalf of oneself.  The spectrum of the word, "smart" and how that intellect is attained is quite wide, so it encompasses many scenarios.